# Why does this viewHelper error occur in TYPO3 and how do I fix ilt?

Tags: typo3, content-management-system, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

When trying to get my custom extension to run in TYPO3 v9.5.11, I get this error message:

```
Undeclared arguments passed to ViewHelper
TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\FlashMessagesViewHelper: renderMode, class, id.
Valid arguments are: queueIdentifier, as
```

[image: The error Message]

I do not exactly know who is trying to pass arguments to the ViewHelper and why it would be failing.

Would creating my own viewHelper be beneficial in this scenarion or is there an easy way of fixing the issue?

Answer (score 2):

in your custom extension, the FlashMessages ViewHelper is used.
You can easily search recursively for `<f:flashMessages` in the extension folder.

The error message gives you the changes, you need to do:

**Valid arguments are: queueIdentifier, as**

But in your extension, the arguments **renderMode, class and id** are used.

You need to remove the invalid arguments, maybe the documentation gives you the needed hints: https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/9.5/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/FlashMessages.html